# Can we create a grouped list to normal list?

Tags: c#, linq

Here it is just an example. Suppose we have class Grouped (Items are gruoped by group name) as given below:

```
public class Grouped
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string GroupName { get; set; }
  public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}

public class Item 
{ 
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

What i need to do is to make a list of Normal Class from the above Grouped Object using only linq c# but not using ForEach or ForLoop.

```
pubic class Normal
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string GroupName { get; set;}
  public string ItemName { get; set;}
}
```

here is an example of list

| Id | Name | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X |
| 1 | A | Y |
| 2 | B | Y |
| 3 | C | X |
| 3 | C | Y |
| 3 | C | Z |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a collection of `Grouped` (and you should, based on the desired output, otherwise there is no source for multiple `Id`s) you can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0) to flatten a nested collection. Something along this lines:

```sql
IEnumerable<Grouped> grouped = ...;
var result = grouped
    .SelectMany(g => g.Items.Select(i => new Normal
    {
        Id = g.Id,
        GroupName = g.GroupName,
        ItemName = i.ItemName
    }))
    .ToList();
```